# Using send built-in action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate

I don't understand meaning and usage of "send" built-in action. You can see here https://codesandbox.io/embed/7467qk4rox a very simple example, with a machine with two parallel state nodes; the second one send events using send built-in action, but this action seems not to be catched, neither in first state node, neither in the second one.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by being specific about your target, [here is a reference](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#multiple-targets) to the docs.

And this is what you're example would look like with the target modifications:

```
const machine = Machine({
    id: "myMachine",
    type: "parallel",
    states: {...},
    on: {
        THREE_KEY: {
            target: ['A.A1', 'B']
        }
    }
});
```

I've also forked your sandbox, and added a working example of this, so that when pressing the key "3", the "THREE_KEY" will target A.A1 & B.

Since your sending events between different states, you might also be interested in the newly added actors model, you can read more about that in the docs [here](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/actors.html#spawning-actors).

I think another important point I can add here is about your use of "send" in the actions, refer to this [section of the documentation](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/actions.html#send-action) which explains:

> The send(...) function is an action creator; it is a pure function
>   that only returns an action object and does not imperatively send an
>   event.